# Issue Fetching Data by Slug as UID in Strapi: Purpose of Making Slug as UID?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, strapi

In Strapi, fetching data by ID is straightforward, but when using slug as a UID (unique identifier), the findOne function doesn't seem to work. Instead, the findMany function is suggested to search for entries with a specific slug. This raises questions about the purpose of making the slug as UID. Is it related to indexing or other factors?

I'm currently working with Strapi, and I've noticed an issue when trying to fetch data using the findOne function with a slug as a UID. Instead, it appears that using the findMany function is the recommended approach. Here's an example of how it's done:

```
const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
  "api::x.x",
  {
    filters: {
      slug: {
        $eq: "slug",
      },
    },
  }
);
```

On the other hand, attempting to fetch data using the findOne function with the slug directly doesn't seem to work:

```
const entry = await strapi.entityService.findOne(
  "api::x.x",
  "slug"
);
```

This situation has left me wondering about the purpose of making the slug as a UID in the first place. Is it solely for indexing purposes or are there other factors involved?